# Is it safe to type passwords on wireless keyboards?

Tags: security, keyboard, wireless-keyboard

Can someone unauthorized snoop into my keyboard's wireless traffic?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe if the channel is encrypted. I use a Logitech keyboard and mouse with Secure Connect receiver. It works at 2.4 GHz. That's the old type, new keyboards and mice by Logitech use the Unifying receivers.

I won't go as far as saying that you can't sniff on wireless keyboards, but when buying new wireless keyboard you want to make sure it uses encrypted signals. Pairing and short signal range are two other factors that at least to some extent make sniffing wireless keyboards difficult.